# Delete files older than x days on hadoop

Tags: ruby, bash, hadoop, fs

I am building a bash script that deletes log files older than x days in a specified directory. As you know "find" is not available on the hadoop fs so I found a neat way of doing this in ruby and was wondering if there is a way to achieve this in bash.

> In Ruby:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby 
require "date"

five_days_ago = Date.parse(Time.now.to_s) - 5
IO.popen("hadoop fs -lsr /tmp").each_line do |line|  
  permissions,replication,user,group,size,mod_date,mod_time,path = *line.split(/\s+/)
  if (mod_date)
    if Date.parse(mod_date.to_s) < five_days_ago
      puts line
      if permissions.split('')[0] == 'd'
        puts "deleting #{path}"
        `hadoop fs -rmr -skipTrash #{path}`
        dirname = path
        next
      end 
      next if path.start_with? dirname
      `hadoop fs -rm -skipTrash #{path}`
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I use in bash, you may try it:

e.g. grep all 8 months old files. Change grep regex pattern as per your need:

```
hadoop fs -ls -R <location> | grep '.*2016-[0-8].*' | awk '{print $8}'
```

Delete files:

```
hadoop fs -rm -r `hadoop fs -ls -R <location> | grep '.*2016-[0-8].*' | awk '{print $8}'`
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I know there are people that don't recommend the use of `ls` for these kind of problems, but I am using `grep -o` to create a new line (so I'll know what strings to expect) and I know what the file name pattern is so this will work perfectly.

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
source_path='/user/'
current_date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
files_ls=$(hdfs dfs -ls "$source_path" | grep -o " 2[0-9]\{3\}-.*")

for line in $files_ls; do
    last_mod=$(echo "$line" | grep -o "[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}")
    file_path=$(echo "$line" | grep -o " /user/.*.log")
    time_diff="$(( ($(date --date="$current_date" +%s) - $(date --date="$last_mod" +%s) )/(60*60*24) ))"
    if [ "$time_diff" -ge "8" ]; then
        echo "hdfs dfs -rm -skipTrash$file_path"
    fi
done
```